# Dynamic tables within dynamic tables (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, filter, dynamic-tables

1. I have two MySQL tables in the same database, each with data.
2. I have a PHP results page that shows the data from the first MySQL table in a dynamic PHP table.
3. One of the fields in the first MySQL table is a comma-separated list of IDs that relate to data in the second MySQL table.
4. I have a second, nested/embedded dynamic PHP table within the first dynamic PHP table that pulls the data from the second MySQL table when the row ID appears in the comma-separated field of the first MySQL table. (i.e. one of the columns in the first dynamic PHP table contains the second, nested dynamic PHP table with data from the second MySQL table

See the PHP/HTML below:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_TravelSite, $TravelSite);
$query_Route = "SELECT * FROM SavedRoutes WHERE RouteCode = '".$_GET['rc']."'";
$Route = mysql_query($query_Route, $TravelSite) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Route = mysql_fetch_assoc($Route);
$totalRows_Route = mysql_num_rows($Route);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>StartPoint</td>
    <td>StartPointLatLng</td>
    <td>EndPoint</td>
    <td>EndPointLatLng</td>
    <td>Waypoints</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Details</td>
    <td>RouteCode</td>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['ID']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['StartPoint']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['StartPointLatLng']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['EndPoint']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['EndPointLatLng']; ?></td>
      <td><p><?php echo $row_Route['Waypoints']; ?></p>
    <?PHP  $string = $row_Route['Waypoints'];
$slashstring = stripslashes($string);
$trimstring = rtrim($slashstring, "', '");
mysql_select_db($database_TravelSite, $TravelSite);
?>
        <p>echo $trimstring = <?PHP echo $trimstring; ?></p>
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>Lng</td>
            <td>Lat</td>
            <td>Name</td>
          </tr>
          <?php
          mysql_select_db($database_TravelSite, $TravelSite);
$query_Markers = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE ID IN('".$trimstring."')";
$Markers = mysql_query($query_Markers, $TravelSite) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Markers = mysql_fetch_assoc($Markers);
$totalRows_Markers = mysql_num_rows($Markers);
           do { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row_Markers['id']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_Markers['Lng']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row_Markers['Lat']; ?></td>
              <td><p>
                <select multiple name="waypoints" id="waypoints">
                  <?php
do {  
?>
                  <option selected value="<?php echo $row_Markers['Lat'] . ", " . $row_Markers['Lng']?>"><?php echo $row_Markers['Lat'] . ", " . $row_Markers['Lng']?></option>
                  <?php
} while ($row_Markers = mysql_fetch_assoc($Markers));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($Markers);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($Markers, 0);
      $row_Markers = mysql_fetch_assoc($Markers);
  }
?>
                </select>
              </p>
                <p><?php echo $row_Markers['Name']; ?></p></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } while ($row_Markers = mysql_fetch_assoc($Markers)); ?>
        </table>
<p>&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['Name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['Details']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_Route['RouteCode']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Route = mysql_fetch_assoc($Route)); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Markers);

mysql_free_result($Route);
?>
```

Now, when ever I run the page the following happens:

- If there is only one item in the nested table (i.e. only one ID from
  the second table appears in the comma-separated field of the first
  table), then it renders perfectly.
- However, if there is more than one (i.e. multiple IDs in the
  comma-separated field), then it renders the first item out to
  infinity (and crashes the browser).

What am I doing wrong? Clearly, nested tables is not the right way of doing what I am trying to do! *n00b* But what is?

Comment: Can you please supply the associated PHP code?

Comment: Please also supply a scheme of the desired query result

Comment: OK, you;re right - rather than talking about it in generals, it is easier to talk in specifics - I will edit the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the fav_food column from the first table, then add a 3rd table - fav_food:

```
ID | fav_Food
1  | 2
1  | 4
1  | 5
1  | 12
```

Then, use a JOIN to select all of John's favorite foods, with details:

```
SELECT *
FROM `fav_food` JOIN `food`
ON `food`.`ID`=`fav_food`.`fav_food`
WHERE `fav_food`.`ID`=1
```

(use a different query to select John's details)

In general, as you said, nested tables is not the best idea when you can use a regular table with JOIN.

Comment: But on creating the favourite foods table, would John have to create a new entry for each of his favourite foods? On creating the data, it is basically a tick-box (the details of which get entered into the comma-separated field) rather than adding each favourite one after the other

Comment: No, user experience will stay the same. You'll have to store user's input as an array, and then pass it to the database using INSERT INTO ... VALUES (array here). See the manual for more detailes about this.

Comment: Don't suppose you have any clever ideas on how to make two "insert" functions under the same button, do you? Can't seem to find a way of doing it. Tried writing it into a "BEGIN... ...COMMIT" statement, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: The button should trigger a server-sider script (php, asp etc.), either via ajax or form action. There you can accept all the vars you want from the user, and use them for as many INSERTS as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution might be to have a separate table for Fav_foods. Something like:

```
ID | UserID | FoodID
 1 |   1    |    2
 2 |   1    |    4
 3 |   1    |    5
```

That would be like: John's favorite foods are foods that have ID 2, 4, 5, ...

Comment: But on creating the favourite foods table, would John have to create a new entry for each of his favourite foods? On creating the data, it is basically a tick-box (the details of which get entered into the comma-separated field) rather than adding each favourite one after the other

Comment: Yes, there would be a new entry for each favourite food. You could do some small iteration that adds all new rows once form(?) is submitted.

Comment: @Kride this is wrong.. User can still tick the boxes and send all of his choices at one time. Also inserting the data to the database wil require only one query, using INSERT...VALUES(several values)